# Why is the `buffer-undo-list` excluded from `(buffer-local-variables)`?

Tags: elisp, undo, desktop

I am modifying `desktop.el` to support restoring the `buffer-undo-list`, and am `push`-ing that list at the tail end of the function `desktop-buffer-info` because the `buffer-undo-list` is not included in the output of the function `buffer-local-variables`.

**Q**:  Is there a built-in method to include the `buffer-undo-list` in the output of the function `buffer-local-variables`?  If not, is there a reason why it's not included?

To make the `buffer-undo-list` get stored into the desktop file, I add:

```
(push (cons 'buffer-undo-list buffer-undo-list) ll)
```

It works, but I'd like to understand why a seemingly buffer-local variable is excluded from the function `buffer-local-variables`.

Comment: As far as I can tell `buffer-undo-list` is *explicitly* excluded from the return value of `buffer-local-variables`, but reasons are unclear. I ran `git blame` on `buffer.{c|h}`; seems like Stefan Monnier is the right person to ask. :-)

Comment: @Constantine Where do you see this being explicitly excluded?

Comment: @tarsius: If you check [`buffer.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/buffer.c?id=83bad90efe943e7c88431b7a71bc1d5cf1304c92#n1274) you can see that `buffer-local-variables` uses `FOR_EACH_PER_BUFFER_OBJECT_AT`. This macro is defined in [`buffer.h`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/buffer.h?id=83bad90efe943e7c88431b7a71bc1d5cf1304c92#n1252). The comment above `FOR_EACH_PER_BUFFER_OBJECT_AT` tells me that `buffer-undo-list` is excluded because it is not a "normal" `Lisp_Object` field of the `buffer` struct. Why it is not normal I do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC `buffer-undo-list` is missing from `buffer-local-variables` by accident.  The accident is that some code clean up ended up making `buffer-local-variables` use the same loop over some of the buffer's local variables, as the loop used when the garbage collector looks for references in a buffer object.

As it turns out, `buffer-undo-list` needs to be handled specially by the GC because we try to throw away elements from it (i.e. some of the entries are treated as "weak references").  E.g. we throw away undo entries which manipulate markers which are not used elsewhere any more.

IOW I think it's just a plain bug, which you might like to report.

Comment: I gather no bug report was created for this? I still see this issue, would really like to be able to save the `buffer-undo-list` with `desktop-save-mode`. :)